# Alert highest number

Tags: javascript, alert

I've made a program where the user has to answer five questions. When the user types in a certain answer a score will add to a matching category. This is a part of the code I've written (with a little help, I'm not very experienced):

```
var orientaal = 0;
var houtig = 0;
var bloemig = 0;
var aromatisch = 0;
var chypre = 0;
var citrus = 0;

var q1 = prompt('Welk element spreekt jou het meest aan? Zet de letters van hoog naar laag (bijv. DBAC). \n\n A. Vuur \n B. Lucht \n C. Aarde \n D. Water')

switch(q1[0]) {
  case 'A':
  case 'a':
    orientaal += 3;
    break;
  case 'B':
  case 'b':
    bloemig += 3;
    break;
  case 'C':
  case 'c':
    houtig += 3;
    break;
  case 'D':
  case 'd':
    citrus += 3;
    break;
}
switch(q1[1]) {
  case 'A':
  case 'a':
    orientaal += 2;
    break;
  case 'B':
  case 'b':
    bloemig += 2;
    break;
  case 'C':
  case 'c':
    houtig += 2;
    break;
  case 'D':
  case 'd':
    citrus += 2;
    break;
}
```

I would like to alert the three categories with the highest score. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var categories = [
  { name: 'orientaal', value: orientaal },
  { name: 'bloemig', value: bloemig },
  { name: 'houtig', value: houtig },
  { name: 'citrus', value: citrus },
  { name: 'aromatisch', value: aromatisch },
  { name: 'chypre', value: chypre }
];

//         sorting in decending order             getting the top 3
categories.sort(function(a, b) { return b.value - a.value; }).slice(0, 3);

// Returns an array of 3 objects
[
  {name: 'orientaal', value: 20},
  {name: 'bloemig', value: 19},
  {name: 'houtig', value: 15},
]
```

Comment: How will you know which categories correspond to the values?

Comment: Oh yeah, good point, completely forgot to match them to the categories :) Let me update the code to use objects instead...